# Функции в питоне

Tags: python

Я плохо разбираюсь в Питоне, но мне срочно надо добавить в эту программу функцию проверки ввода. Как это можно реализовать?

```
import sys

print("Стороны:")
a = float(input("a = "))
b = float(input("b = "))
c = float(input("c = "))

if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
    print("Треугольник существует")
else:
    print("Треугольник не существует")
    sys.exit(1)

print("Введите угол")
u = float(input("угол = "))

if u > 90:
    print("Треугольник тупоугольный")

if u == 90:
    print("Треугольник прямоугольный")

if u > 60 and u < 90:
    print("Треугольник разносторонний")

if u == 60:
    print("Треугольник равносторонний")

if u < 60:
    print("Треугольник остроугольный")
```

Comment: а как вы по значению одного угла определяете, что треугольник равносторонний?

Answer (score 0):

Может вот так пойдет? Для каждого ввода...
Вместо:

```
a = float(input("a = "))
b = float(input("b = "))
c = float(input("c = "))
```

Сделать вот так:

```
a = input("a = ")
while not a.isnumeric():
    print("Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте снова: ")
    a = input("a = ")
a = float(a)
b = input("b = ")
while not b.isnumeric():
    print("Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте снова: ")
    b = input("b = ")
b = float(b)
c = input("c = ")
while not c.isnumeric():
    print("Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте снова: ")
    c = input("c = ")
c = float(c)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]